# Can't update or delete row from table (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, bytea

I have table with `bytea` field. When I try to delete a row from this table, I get such error:

```
[42704] ERROR: large object 0 does not exist
```

Can you help me in this situation?

Edit. Information from command `\d photo`:

```
    Table "public.photo"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
------------+------------------------+-----------
 id         | character varying(255) | not null
 ldap_name  | character varying(255) | not null
 file_name  | character varying(255) | not null
 image_data | bytea                  | 
Indexes:
    "pk_photo" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "photo_file_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (file_name)
    "photo_ldap_name" btree (ldap_name)
Triggers:
    remove_unused_large_objects BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON photo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lo_manage('image_data')
```

Comment: In psql perform `\d photo` and show the result (edit the question).

Comment: You seem to be confused about large objects. Your field type is `image_data` of type `bytea`, but you're also trying to treat it like a large-object reference to `pg_largeobject`. What is actually in that field? What query results in the error?

Comment: Maybe the `lo_manage()` function is not picky enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the trigger:

```
drop trigger remove_unused_large_objects on photo;
```

Comment: As I correctly understood, I don't need this trigger for bytea field, but I need such cleaning for large objects. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, someone (maybe you) have changed the way photos are stored and now the trigger is not relevant.

Comment: Right, if you're using large objects. But then you'd have an integer or oid column to refer to them. Unless your code is doing something scary and wrong like jamming the oid into a bytea column.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

delete from photo where primarykey = 'you want to delete';